# fabric.js arrows and arrow head rotating

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I want to create arrows in fabric.js that connect two objects together.

I have a jsFiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/xvcyzh9p/45/ (thanks to @gco).

The above allows you to create two objects (two rectangles) and connect them together with a line.

```
function addChildLine(options) {
canvas.off('object:selected', addChildLine);

// add the line
var fromObject = canvas.addChild.start;
var toObject = options.target;
var from = fromObject.getCenterPoint();
var to = toObject.getCenterPoint();
var line = new fabric.Line([from.x, from.y, to.x, to.y], {
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 5,
    selectable: false
});
canvas.add(line);
// so that the line is behind the connected shapes
line.sendToBack();

// add a reference to the line to each object
fromObject.addChild = {
    // this retains the existing arrays (if there were any)
    from: (fromObject.addChild && fromObject.addChild.from) || [],
    to: (fromObject.addChild && fromObject.addChild.to)
}
fromObject.addChild.from.push(line);
toObject.addChild = {
    from: (toObject.addChild && toObject.addChild.from),
    to: (toObject.addChild && toObject.addChild.to) || []
}
toObject.addChild.to.push(line);

// to remove line references when the line gets removed
line.addChildRemove = function () {
    fromObject.addChild.from.forEach(function (e, i, arr) {
        if (e === line)
            arr.splice(i, 1);
    });
    toObject.addChild.to.forEach(function (e, i, arr) {
        if (e === line)
            arr.splice(i, 1);
    });
}
canvas.addChild = undefined;
}

function addChildMoveLine(event) {
    canvas.on(event, function (options) {
        var object = options.target;
        var objectCenter = object.getCenterPoint();
        // udpate lines (if any)
        if (object.addChild) {
            if (object.addChild.from)
                object.addChild.from.forEach(function (line) {
                    line.set({ 'x1': objectCenter.x, 'y1': objectCenter.y });
                })
                if (object.addChild.to)
                    object.addChild.to.forEach(function (line) {
                        line.set({ 'x2': objectCenter.x, 'y2': objectCenter.y });
                    })
                    }

        canvas.renderAll();
    });
}
```

I have tried looking at other examples to create an arrow in fabric.js but to implement in gco's fiddle has been a pain.

My best attempt at this can be found here: http://example.legalobjects.com/

**It looks something like this:**
[image]

Some of the problems I have experience are:

- The arrow head not moving around the in the correct direction
- The arrow head (or multiple arrow heads) breaking when more than one arrow is added to the canvas - they get "stuck" for some reason.
- Arrow head/line not moving around the object

**When adding more than one arrow this happens:**
[image]

If anyone has any ideas or can help at all, I would be very appreciative!

Thanks.

Comment: See this: http://robferguson.org/2016/01/21/adding-support-for-ports-and-connectors-to-fabric-js/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's go through your issues.

> The arrow head (or multiple arrow heads) breaking when more than one arrow is added to the canvas - they get "stuck" for some reason.

This is caused by you using a single `triangle` global variable, which means there can only really be one triangle. This is trivial to resolve though - just replace `triangle` with `line.triangle`, so that it becomes a property of the line it belongs to.

E.g. instead of

```
triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
```

simply use

```
line.triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
```

and consequently replace

```
line.addChildRemove();
line.remove();
line.triangle.remove();
```

with

```
line.triangle.remove();
line.addChildRemove();
line.remove();
```

> The arrow head not moving around the in the correct direction

This is a simple shortcoming of your direction logic. There's no part that's really wrong, except that it doesn't do what you desire. I reworked it to the following snippet:

```
object.addChild.to.forEach(function(line) {
    var x = objectCenter.x;
    var y = objectCenter.y;
    var xdis = REC_WIDTH/2 + TRI_WIDTH/2;
    var ydis = REC_HEIGHT/2 + TRI_HEIGHT/2;
    var horizontal = Math.abs(x - line.x2) > Math.abs(y - line.y2);
    line.set({
        'x2': x + xdis * (horizontal ? (x < line.x2 ? 1 : -1) :                      0),
        'y2': y + ydis * (horizontal ?                      0 : (y < line.y2 ? 1 : -1))
    });
    line.triangle.set({
        'left': line.x2, 'top': line.y2,
        'angle': calcArrowAngle(line.x1, line.y1, line.x2, line.y2)
    });
});
```

The basic idea is to offset *either* the X *or* the Y coordinate, based on whether the X or Y distance of the two objects are greater.

> Arrow head/line not moving around the object.

Another logic flaw in the snippet posted just above. Using `x2` and `y2` for the calculation of the triangle is correct, since you're basing its location of the **target** rectangle. For the line however, you want to base calculations on the location of the **source** rectangle, so you need to use `x1` and `y1` respectively. So we can change the above code again to:

```
object.addChild.to.forEach(function(line) {
    var x = objectCenter.x;
    var y = objectCenter.y;
    var xdis = REC_WIDTH/2 + TRI_WIDTH/2;
    var ydis = REC_HEIGHT/2 + TRI_HEIGHT/2;
    var horizontal = Math.abs(x - line.x1) > Math.abs(y - line.y1);
    line.set({
        'x2': x + xdis * (horizontal ? (x < line.x1 ? 1 : -1) :                      0),
        'y2': y + ydis * (horizontal ?                      0 : (y < line.y1 ? 1 : -1))
    });
    line.triangle.set({
        'left': line.x2, 'top': line.y2,
        'angle': calcArrowAngle(line.x1, line.y1, line.x2, line.y2)
    });
});
```

For a more seamless experience, you also need to change how the recalculations are invoked. Currently you only update the part of the line that is connected to the rectangle that you're actually moving, but not the other half of the connection.
I implemented this by replacing the `to` and `from` arrays with a simple, single `lines` array, and adding properties `fromObject` and `toObject` to each line element - on every update, both ends of the line get updated, like so:

```
if (object.addChild && object.addChild.lines) {
    object.addChild.lines.forEach(function(line) {
        var fcenter = line.fromObject.getCenterPoint(),
            fx = fcenter.x,
            fy = fcenter.y,
            tcenter = line.toObject.getCenterPoint(),
            tx = tcenter.x,
            ty = tcenter.y,
            xdis = REC_WIDTH/2 + TRI_WIDTH/2,
            ydis = REC_HEIGHT/2 + TRI_HEIGHT/2,
            horizontal = Math.abs(tx - line.x1) > Math.abs(ty - line.y1)
        line.set({
            'x1': fx,
            'y1': fy,
            'x2': tx + xdis * (horizontal ? (tx < line.x1 ? 1 : -1) :                       0),
            'y2': ty + ydis * (horizontal ?                       0 : (ty < line.y1 ? 1 : -1)),
        });
        line.triangle.set({
            'left': line.x2, 'top': line.y2,
            'angle': calcArrowAngle(line.x1, line.y1, line.x2, line.y2)
        });
    });
}
```

In addition to that you have an unhandled use case: You get an error if you select a box, delete it and then click "add child". You can prevent that by simply testing for `null` at the top of the `addChild` function like so:

```
if(canvas.getActiveObject() == null)
{
    return;
}
```

With all of the above, I created [an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ka7nhvbq/2/).

---

Update, years later: it turns out that you can drag to select multiple rectangles, which puts them in a group that you can move as a whole, and doing that would leave the arrow behind in my solution above (as noted by "sugars" in the comments). The solution to that is to embed the updating code into its own function and recursively call that for each object of the target object of the event is a group. Then you also run into the problem of the object coordinates becoming relative to the center of the group, so you have to adjust for that too. I made an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Siguza/xdgbh3n8/2/) with that fixed as well.

The code for the new update function is:

```js
function addChildMoveLine(event) {
    canvas.on(event, function(options) {
        if((function updateObject(object, offset) {
            // update child objects, if any
            if (object.getObjects) {
                var off = object.getCenterPoint();
                return object.getObjects().reduce(function(flag, obj) {
                    return updateObject(obj, off) || flag;
                }, false);
            }
            if (!offset)
                offset = { x: 0, y: 0 };
            // otherwise udpate lines, if any
            if (object.addChild && object.addChild.lines) {
                object.addChild.lines.forEach(function(line) {
                    var fcenter = line.sourceObject.getCenterPoint(),
                        fx = fcenter.x + offset.x,
                        fy = fcenter.y + offset.y,
                        tcenter = line.targetObject.getCenterPoint(),
                        tx = tcenter.x + offset.x,
                        ty = tcenter.y + offset.y,
                        xdis = REC_WIDTH/2 + TRI_WIDTH/2,
                        ydis = REC_HEIGHT/2 + TRI_HEIGHT/2,
                        horizontal = Math.abs(tx - line.x1) > Math.abs(ty - line.y1);
                    line.set({
                        'x1': fx,
                        'y1': fy,
                        'x2': tx + xdis * (horizontal ? (tx < line.x1 ? 1 : -1) :                       0),
                        'y2': ty + ydis * (horizontal ?                       0 : (ty < line.y1 ? 1 : -1)),
                    });
                    line.triangle.set({
                        'left': line.x2, 'top': line.y2,
                        'angle': calcArrowAngle(line.x1, line.y1, line.x2, line.y2)
                    });
                });
                return true; // re-render
            }
            return false; // no re-render needed
        })(options.target)) {
            canvas.renderAll();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your JS Fiddle still has some bugs in handlind lines when there are many rects and lines as you can see from https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDOUR.png

Comment: Could you describe the steps to reproduce such a case? Everything I tried works fine...

Comment: @Siguze, well every time when I have 3 rects and 2 lines, it happens for movement of at least one of the rects not sure which but it is easy to try all 3 of them. And things get much worse if you have more rects and lines see https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3nLm.png

Comment: Never mind, I just found that myself as well. [Fixed](https://jsfiddle.net/ka7nhvbq/2/). Anything else?

Comment: Well, I don't like naming in the code, actually most of it but I think this is not your issue.

Comment: @Siguza, this is perfect! I have one more last question quickly! What if I wanted to create doubles arrows in one click, e.g [something like this](http://i.imgur.com/r59OWYP.png). I understand that I can click box A, click add child button, click box B, click box B, click add child button and then click box A. But that requires 2 clicks of the addChild button to creates the double arrow. How can I do it so it create a double arrow in one click. Thanks for all your hard work and help! The solution is perfect!

Comment: @Tahmid That's pretty easy. In `addChild`, just set a property on `canvas.addChild` to indicate whether or not you want a bidirectional relation or not, and then in `addChildLine` you encapsulate the line creation in an internal function that you call with `(fromObject, toObject)` either way, and if it's a bidirectional relation, you just call it with `(toObject, fromObject)` as well. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Siguza/ym68db9n/).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: @Siguza, I've noticed a problem with your code that I am confused about. When trying to save the canvas to JSON it throws an error in the console. The original jsFiddle I provided that connects the boxes via a simple line allows the canvas to be saved as JSON, please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/xvcyzh9p/46/. Your updated fiddle for some reason does not allow saving to JSON and instead throws an error, please see here: https://jsfiddle.net/ka7nhvbq/6/. The function that I am using to save to JSON is as follows: `var json = JSON.stringify(canvas.toJSON()); console.log(json);`.

Comment: @Tahmid That was my fault... I created an unfortunate property naming collision. I created properties on `line` called `fromObject` and `toObject`, unknowing that `toObject` is expected to be a function that returns a JSON representation of the object. I hence renamed those properties to `sourceObject` and `targetObject` and created [another Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Siguza/ka7nhvbq/7/).

Comment: I would have never guessed that! Thank you! I appreciate your help. Awesome.

Comment: There is another problem in the example. If you drag to select multiple rects and move them, you will find that multiple arrows will not be moved:( @Siguza

Comment: @sugars ok wow, that was cursed. But I fixed that too: https://jsfiddle.net/Siguza/xdgbh3n8/